# Can i develop react native IOS apps on windows pc

Tags: react-native

Can i able to develop react-native IOS apps in my windows pc, if possible then please reply with what are the requirements and setup require to develop and run react-native ios apps in windows pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

Check the official 'getting started guide' here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#requirements

> Requirements  OS X - This guide assumes OS X which is needed for iOS
>   development.

You need to run xCode in order to build app on Simulator or iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build, package, and deploy IOS apps from a pc or linux machine using a couple different methods.

One would be using a service like BuddyBuild (https://www.buddybuild.com/). You can just point them at the git repo you want to package, give them your certificate, and go from there.

Your other option would be to rent a cloud machine running some version of OS X. They are typically pretty cheap and you wouldn't need to do it very often.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cloud build service like Mobile Center or Circle CI, or run a "hackintosh" virtual machine image in VirtualBox.

The latter breaks the Apple MacOS EULA, and the former has longer feedback cycles to learn if your code builds or not.